# HTML5 pushstate with hash fallback library with examples and tutorials

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, pushstate

I'm trying to add routing to my website that is fairly intuitive for someone else to takeover. History.js works, but it can be confusing to implement and am struggling to find tutorials and examples.  I like Davis.js, but again, tutorials and examples are slim.  I know there are others, BBQ, Routing in Backbone, jQuery Address, so forth.

Is there a best choice that has pushstate support and fallbacks to hash support (needs to be cross browser/cross device) with tutorials and a couple implementations?

Thanks.

Comment: Fallbacks to hashbangs doesn't sound like a good option, especially not if you're handing over to someone else. They can't work when javascript is disabled, require extra support on the server, and the hashbang urls will be broken when you stop supporting them in a year or two. http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs

Comment: Davis.js doesn't fall back to using the hash for routing, I don't think this is a good idea in general, just fall back to full page loads if the browser doesn't support pushState.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten to play with client side routing much yet.  That said I'd probably start with Backbone and see how it goes.  I've been really impressed with Backbone so far.
Unfortunately the best bet is probably to try things until you find a library that fits your project.